# jQuery event.target element's sibling

Tags: jquery

This is the snippet I have to work with --

```
$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
  if(!$(e.target).is('.element')) {
    if ($('.element').hasClass('open')) {
      // next line doesn't work
      $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp(150);
    }
  }
});
```

What I would like to do is get the `.element` with that class to slide its neighboring element (in this case ul). I know why using `$(this)` won't work here, but it gives the idea of what I'd like to do. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please paste your HTML here

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` if you work with jQuery’s built-in event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '.element.open', function () {
    $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp(150);
});
```